# How to correctly use dependency Injection with .Net Core SignalR

Tags: .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm learning .Net Core SignalR and investigating how I could use it with my app live charts. I play with some examples on the net and they all work, but I don't know how to use SignalR with database polling. I'm getting below error:

> Cannot access a disposed object ...

I'm assuming it is related to my contex is being disposed after request is completed. I'm using dependency injection.

ChatController

```
public class ChatController : ControllerBase
{
    private IChatService _chatService;
    private IChatContext<ChatHub> _hub;

    public ChatController(IChatContext<ChatHub> hub, IChatService chatService)
    {
        _hub = hub;
        _chatService = chatService;
    }
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var timerManager = new TimerManager(() => _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transferchatdata", _chatService.ChatDataByProds()));

        return Ok(new { Message = "Request Completed" });
    }
}
```

ChatService

```
public interface IChatService
{
    IEnumerable<ChatDataByProd> ChatDataByProds();
}

public class ChatService : IChatService
{
    private ChatContext _context;

    public ChatService(ChatContext  context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ChatDataByProd> ChatDataByProds()
    {
       return _context.ChatDataByProds;
    }
}
```

ChatHub

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub
{
}
```

Comment: What is `TimerManager`?

Comment: It's just a static class that manage when next time we check for data in db, but I will change it for SqlDependency in the later time

Comment: Well, it's not a static class because you're newing it up, so you probably mean there's a static field on it storing a timer. That's your issue. Statics and DI are like oil and water.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a EF Core context that is a scoped lifetime service, which means per-request lifetime in ASP.NET Core. Your `ChatService` must have a longer lifetime than a HTTP request, and a single instance of the database context would be disposed by the container while you are still holding the reference to it.

Thus, you need to obtain an `IServiceProvider` container in the ctor of `ChatService`, and `GetService` the database context each time when you need to access the database.

Comment: and how do I do that? Could you provide an example? I through IServiceProvider will also need to be injected and its life time is the same as context.

Comment: You can resolve `IServiceProvider` without any registry, and it would be the properly referencing the `IServiceProvider` of the current scope.